# Is everything halal in heaven?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

I saw this on Reddit's [/r/Islam](https://www.reddit.com/r/islam/comments/5u1q8g/til_that_alcohol_in_heaven_is_halal/ddrh5h3/): "I think everything is halal in Jannah.  Correct me if I'm wrong."

**Question**: Is everything halal in heaven?

The Reddit author wasn't corrected.  It seems unlikely to me (how could e.g. shirk or murder be halal in jannah?), but it may be that people are inhibited/prevented from performing haram acts, along the lines of drinking wine being halal in jannah:

> There will be circulated among them a cup [of wine] from a flowing spring, White and delicious to the drinkers; No bad effect is there in it, nor from it will they be intoxicated. -- [Qur'an 37:45-47](https://quran.com/37/45)

Comment: I think to answer this question, one must first define what is haram in heaven and what isn't. Is it even possible to murder someone in heaven? Or is the thought of it or the intention of it enough to be counted as haram? Will people in heaven think those thoughts? Do we have "free will" in heaven? As the majority believes, Iblees was in heaven once, and he himself stood up against Gods commandment, which of course was haram. Will some of the people in heaven do something like this? I think the real answer to this question really is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

In Jannah, the good pious believer will be rewarded. Haram food here such as wine is haram because it intoxicates people while in Jannah it will be made halal so it wont't intoxicate people. There won't be any murders or sins in heaven as everyone will be happy and if they wish for anything it will be given to them. If they are in Jannah, how can they commit shirk while they know Allah is there?Allah wouldn't have accepted them into Jannah if this happened. There will be no reason to sin in Jannah and no one will as Allah has given them everlasting happiness and joy. As for haram acts like eating pork etc, it is haram for a reason and so we won't be able to eat pork or do any other sins that are haram. The believer's heart will be free of sin, evil desires etc and they wouldn't want to do haram acts there.

Answer (score -2):

I think the verse addresses what you are asking perfectly.

*No bad effect is there in it, nor from it will they be intoxicated*

**Had it still had it's affect in the same way it has on earth, then it would be Haram.**

Our life in heaven/hell is very different. Our **body** can endure things it couldn't endure before. Either being burnt in fire permanently or smelling the aroma of heaven which would have made humans (on earth) go unconscious from miles away. In addition our whole **surroundings** are different. Rivers of milk and Honey.
*Perhaps* our body can endure the same wine differently or perhaps it's processed differently. But that would be just speculation. We either need to wait a couple years or have a narration from someone who was connected to Allah.

Basically heaven is like living in a different realm. Like us going from the Hades's underworld to Zeus's Olympus!

Answer (score -5):

It is Halal to have something like Fire. U may be like whut! For expample think about Charizard aka Lizardon right. Charizard is a Fire Type Pokémon with literal Fire right. I thought Fire was Haram because ya know it is commonly associated with Jinns and I thought it will be Halal to censor the Fire to Water. My Uncle told me Fire is halal because Allah will allow u to have anything so it is Halal btw. Yes, I am a Muslim Peace be upon u if u r Reading this Comment and I hope u pass the As-Sirat Bridge in the Day of Judgement and I hope that it will be finish like a speed of Lightning.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. I can't see how this answers or even adresses the topic of the question asked in a meaningful manner. See [answer].